# TortoiseSVN abnormally download huge data despite the repo is small

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

Server: VisualSVN

Sometimes ToitoiseSVN becomes very slow on network transfer for all actions (eg. log, update, commit, checkout). When that happens, even when checking out a small project (less than 10KB) can be weird, since in the checkout message window, the total transfer file size can be over several MB and even bigger. However, if browse the repo in browser and download file manually, the transfer rate is normal. What happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess: you're using SSPI (Domain) authentication.

Problem: the huge amount of data that's transferred comes from repeated authentications (once for every single data packet sent/received). This sometimes happens if the server loses connection to the domain controller or has other problems related with the domain controller.

So: check your server setup, make sure the connection isn't dropped between your svn server and the domain controller and also make sure that both your client pc and svn server are properly joined to the domain.

And it helps if the user *GUEST* isn't active on the svn server and your client pc.

Comment: somehow either my PC or the SVN server is not properly connecting to domain server. Rebooting both machines resolved this issue. Thank you!